# Django: ошибка ImproperlyConfigured при запуске сервера

Tags: python, django

При попытке запустить локальный сервер возникает ошибка:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
 The included URLconf 
'<module 'polls.urls' from... 
does not appear to have any patterns in it. 
If you see valid patterns in the file 
then the issue is probably 
caused by a circular import.
```

С шаблонами вроде все в порядке, значит, ошибка возникает из-за рекурсивного импорта? Как это исправить?

urls.py проекта:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

urls.py приложения:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

ulrpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    ]
```

Comment: А у вас polls.urls то есть?

Comment: Второй код и есть urls.py в папке polls